# Angular 6 - assets not including

Tags: angular, typescript, build, angular6

my app does not include assets directory, when i'm building app or starting a live server

**angular.json**

```
       "assets": [
          "src/favicon.ico",
          "src/assets",
          "src/manifest.json"
        ],
```

**Directory structure**

[image]

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: assets folder not including in bundle

Comment: @t-x check [my post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51837595/1477703) on SO here it should help you as well

Answer (score 0):

I think assets folder is empty that's why it is not exists in your **dist** directory.