# Unable to call javascript function from Typescript in Angular 6

Tags: angular

The javascript function (help) below is not being called from ngOnInit()?

In web console: ERROR ReferenceError: "help is not defined"

Would you know how this can be done?

---

src/assets/myjs.js:

```
function help() {
    console.log("hilfe");   
}
```

---

src/app/highlight.directive.ts:

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

declare function help() : any;

@Directive({
  selector: '[appHighlight]'
})
export class HighlightDirective implements OnInit {

  constructor(el: ElementRef) { 
    el.nativeElement.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    help();
  }

}
```

---

angular.json:

```
...

    "styles": [
         "src/styles.css"
    ],
    "scripts": [
        "src/assets/myjs.js"
    ],
},
...
```

Comment: You need to declare that this function exists in the global scope: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/by-example.html#global-functions, https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-global-scripts#using-global-libraries-inside-your-app. But the main question is: why do you have that JS script and this global function in the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ES6/TS

Simply export your function Help in help.ts

```
export default function Help(){}
```

Import anywhere by

```
import Help from 'help'
```

Answer (score 2):

What about exporting your function like

```
module.exports.help = () => {
      console.log("hilfe");   
}
```

Then

```
const helper = require("./pathofyourfile");
```

Answer (score 1):

@simon-reeves

> "scripts": [
>           "src/assets/myjs.js"
>       ],

I had to put `testjs.js` file into `assets` folder and applied path like below

moreover, make sure that `assets` section is defined an above and that file is exists by this path in sources

[image]

In addition, check content of the generated `scripts.js` file , cuz, it should contains your `help` function, e.g. in my case it's `myalert` function

[image]

hope it should help you

Answer (score 1):

There are two sections in the angular.json file for scripts.  One is "architect:" the other is "test:".  Is your scripts definition in both places?

```
    "scripts": [ "src/assets/myjs.js" ],
```

And I doubt this second point would make a difference, but I was guided by one post to create a sub-directory under assets called "js". Like this...

```
    "scripts": [ "src/assets/js/myjs.js" ],
```

You also might try an alert('hilfe') in your js function rather than a console.log()... although either should work.

Your setup seems pretty correct otherwise.

In additional to that you need to declare the same function in your component file. For example the function name is JavaScript file is help(), you need to declare it just above the component like:
    declare function help(): any;
and then call the help function where you want to call in that file.