# Unable to call a JS function from Typescript in Angular 13

Tags: javascript, angular, angular13

I'm trying to call the following function, `LoadMultiSelect()`, from one of my components because I am using a non-Angular library:

https://ibnujakaria.github.io/multiple-select-js/

This works perfectly in the console:

```js
new MultipleSelect('#select-multiple-language', {
  placeholder: 'Select Language'
})
```

And loads the JS component.

Later, I try adding it in Angular, but I cannot find how to.

I tried to export the JS function in two ways:

```
export default function LoadMultiSelect() {
  new MultipleSelect('#select-multiple-language', {
    placeholder: 'Select Language'
  });
}
```

And like this:

```
LoadMultiSelect() {
  new MultipleSelect('#select-multiple-language', {
    placeholder: 'Select Language'
  });
}

var multiselect = new LoadMultiSelect();

export { multiselect };
```

I created a file to load the exported function:

> assets/js/multiselect.js

Later, I added it in my `build` in the `scripts` section from my `angular.json` like this:

```
"scripts": [
              "./node_modules/multiple-select-js/dist/js/multiple-select.js",
              "src/assets/js/multiselect.js"
            ]
```

And then I tried to add it in my component like this:

```
import LoadMultiSelect from '../../../../../assets/js/multiselect';

import LoadMultiSelect from 'src/assets/js/multiselect';
```

But nothing works, I get this error:

> Could not find a declaration file for module
> '../../../../../assets/js/multiselect'.
> '/Users/fanmixco/Documents/GitHub/holma-bootstrap/src/assets/js/multiselect.js'
> implicitly has an 'any' type.

Or others, any idea what I'm doing wrong?

P.S.:

1. Also, I tried using `require`, but it also failed.
2. I already tested previous solutions with an older version of Angular:

- [Unable to call javascript function from Typescript in Angular 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51834966/unable-to-call-javascript-function-from-typescript-in-angular-6)
- [How to call JavaScript functions from Typescript in Angular 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49526681/how-to-call-javascript-functions-from-typescript-in-angular-5)
- [calling javascript function from typescript angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43530096/calling-javascript-function-from-typescript-angular-2)

Comment: If you plan to close it, show me how the angular 6 or earlier versions are compatible.

Comment: _"I added it in my build in the scripts section from my angular.json like this:

    "src/assets/js/multiselect.js"
"_ Why? Remove it. It makes no sense. Programming by guessing doesn't work. The second snippet isn't valid JavaScript/TypeScript.

Comment: This whole approach looks pretty strange. Is there a reason for this approach? What is `MultipleSelect`? Why do you use the extension `*.js`?

Comment: Hi @jabaa, I have a non-Angular JS library that I must call from my component. That's the main challenge.

Comment: Does this library already exist? Does it contain the invalid code like the second snippet?

Comment: Yes, it does exist, if I run this code `new MultipleSelect('#select-multiple-language', {
    placeholder: 'Select Language'
  });` in the JS console works perfectly.

Comment: Strange. I get a syntax error. Looks like your browser is broken.

Comment: But it still contains invalid code and syntax errors. I'm not sure it's even possible to load modules in `angular.js` in `scripts`. `import LoadMultiSelect from '../../../../../assets/js/multiselect';` is a TypeScript import, not a JavaScript import. I would provide a declaration file, remove it from `scripts` and import it using TypeScript.

Comment: For the close voters and minus one voters without comments, you can read the answer. This is not an easy topic and a new change in Angular 13 and most likely the next versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried this in my local system, with some random file like below,

```
export function MultipleSelect(val1, val2){
    console.log('Be awesome always', val1, ' and ', val2);
}
```

now I import this in my component like this,

```
export class AppComponent {
    title = 'stackoverflow-examples';
    declare MultipleSelect: any;

    constructor(
      private fb: FormBuilder
    ) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
      import('./someRandomFile').then(randomFile=>{
        randomFile.MultipleSelect('one', 'two')
      });
    }
}
```

In order for this file to be imported in the angular ts file, I must allow it in `tsconfig.json` by allowing the js import as given below,

`"allowJs": true`

see the result in the console below,

[image]

**Note: If unable to load the file from node_modules, please put that in regular folder like `asset` and do the import as suggested**

Comment: I keep facing: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'

Comment: Also, it seems to be skipping this library altogether: `"./node_modules/multiple-select-js/dist/js/multiple-select.js"` any idea?

Comment: I had a same situation with a js library, I kept the library out from nodemodules as that was not required to be upgraded/updated in future but our functionality was dependent on it so removed it from there and kept it in assets like folder and imported it

Comment: It worked. Can you add that to your answer? Then, I'll accept it because this is a tricky topic. Thanks!

Comment: This topic is quite tricky, was tried to be closed even twice and even got -1 votes when this is a real issue in Angular 13. Thanks.

Comment: hey sure dude, i have updated in notes :) please do the honor